# Fetch data exist in another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following tables :
**DF1**

```
var1    var2    var3    Ars_0   Ars_1   Ars_2   Ars_3   Ars_4   Ars_5   Ars_6   Ars_7
x   y1  z1  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   0.000
x   y2  z1  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   0.000
x   y1  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   0.000
x   y2  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   0.000
y   y1  z1  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
y   y2  z1  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
y   y1  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
y   y2  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
z   y1  z1  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
z   y2  z1  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
z   y1  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
z   y2  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
```

**DF2**

```
var1    var2    var3    Ars_0   Ars_1   Ars_2   Ars_3   Ars_4   Ars_5   Ars_6
x   y1  z1  0.935   0.065   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
x   y2  z1  1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
x   y1  z2  0.146   0.000   0.854   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
x   y2  z2  0.520   0.377   0.103   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
y   y1  z1  0.939   0.060   0.000   0.001   0.000   0.000   0.000
y   y2  z1  0.987   0.013   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
y   y1  z2  0.175   0.052   0.773   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
y   y2  z2  0.000   0.000   1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
z   y1  z1  0.948   0.052   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
z   y2  z1  0.981   0.019   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
```

I want all rows from DF2 and rows which does not exist in DF2 but exist in DF1 (based on var1, var2 and var3). If a column does not exist, the whole column should be fetched. For e.g. Ars_7 exist in DF1 but not exist in DF2 so whole could be added in the final output.

**Desired Output**

```
var1    var2    var3    Ars_0   Ars_1   Ars_2   Ars_3   Ars_4   Ars_5   Ars_6   Ars_7
x   y1  z1  0.935   0.065   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
x   y2  z1  1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
x   y1  z2  0.146   0.000   0.854   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
x   y2  z2  0.520   0.377   0.103   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
y   y1  z1  0.939   0.060   0.000   0.001   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000
y   y2  z1  0.987   0.013   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000
y   y1  z2  0.175   0.052   0.773   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000
y   y2  z2  0.000   0.000   1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000
z   y1  z1  0.948   0.052   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000
z   y2  z1  0.981   0.019   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000
z   y1  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
z   y2  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
```

**R Code**

```
x1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
text='var1  var2    var3    Ars_0   Ars_1   Ars_2   Ars_3   Ars_4   Ars_5   Ars_6
x   y1  z1  0.935   0.065   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
x   y2  z1  1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
x   y1  z2  0.146   0.000   0.854   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
x   y2  z2  0.520   0.377   0.103   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
y   y1  z1  0.939   0.060   0.000   0.001   0.000   0.000   0.000
y   y2  z1  0.987   0.013   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
y   y1  z2  0.175   0.052   0.773   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
y   y2  z2  0.000   0.000   1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
z   y1  z1  0.948   0.052   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
z   y2  z1  0.981   0.019   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
')

x2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                 text='var1 var2    var3    Ars_0   Ars_1   Ars_2   Ars_3   Ars_4   Ars_5   Ars_6   Ars_7
x   y1  z1  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   0.000
x   y2  z1  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   0.000
x   y1  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   0.000
x   y2  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   0.000
y   y1  z1  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
y   y2  z1  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
y   y1  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
y   y2  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
z   y1  z1  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
z   y2  z1  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
z   y1  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
z   y2  z2  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000
')
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you post the desired output. I think you want to match all rows in x2 with x1 plus whatever in x1 that is not matching in x2. That would be a full-join: `merge(x1, x2, all=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks. I have added desired output. Full join does not return the desired output. It returns 22 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base `R`, you can left-join using `merge` to match `x1` and `x2` by the keys `c("var1","var2","var3")`. Then you can anti-join whatever in `x2` that does not match in `x1` by the same keys in the merge. You need to make sure you only select the key columns on the right-hand side of the merge plus whatever column is missing in `x1` from `x2`:

```
cols <- c("var1","var2","var3") # keys

missingCol <- setdiff(names(x2), names(x1)) # column(s) missing in x1 but that exist in x2

# left-join for the first component
a <- merge(x1, x2[c(cols, missingCol)], all.x=TRUE, by = c("var1","var2","var3"))

# anti join x2 on x1, see the use of `interaction`
b <- x2[!interaction(x2[cols]) %in% interaction(x1[cols]), ]

# "stack" tables with rbind
out <- do.call(rbind, list(a, b))
```

Result:

```
> out
   var1 var2 var3 Ars_0 Ars_1 Ars_2 Ars_3 Ars_4 Ars_5 Ars_6 Ars_7
1     x   y1   z1 0.935 0.065 0.000 0.000     0     0     0     0
2     x   y1   z2 0.146 0.000 0.854 0.000     0     0     0     0
3     x   y2   z1 1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000     0     0     0     0
4     x   y2   z2 0.520 0.377 0.103 0.000     0     0     0     0
5     y   y1   z1 0.939 0.060 0.000 0.001     0     0     0     1
6     y   y1   z2 0.175 0.052 0.773 0.000     0     0     0     1
7     y   y2   z1 0.987 0.013 0.000 0.000     0     0     0     1
8     y   y2   z2 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000     0     0     0     1
9     z   y1   z1 0.948 0.052 0.000 0.000     0     0     0     1
10    z   y2   z1 0.981 0.019 0.000 0.000     0     0     0     1
11    z   y1   z2 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000     1     1     1     1
12    z   y2   z2 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000     1     1     1     1
```

#### with `data.table`

We repeat the same process as above —that we need to piece together the left-join and the anti-join tables in a stack but with friendly syntax of `data.table` and its usual computational efficiency:

```
# data.table solution
library(data.table)

cols <- c("var1","var2","var3") # keys
missingCol <- setdiff(names(x2), names(x1)) # column(s) missing in x1 but that exist in x2


setDT(x1) # need to use `setDT` to make data.frames into data.table objects
setDT(x2)

a <- x2[, c(cols, missingCol), with=F][x1, on=cols] # left join
b <- x2[!x1, on=cols] # anti join

res3 <- rbindlist(list(a, b), use.names = TRUE) # bind rows

setcolorder(res3, names(x2)) # order columns as x2
```

Result:

```
> res3
    var1 var2 var3 Ars_0 Ars_1 Ars_2 Ars_3 Ars_4 Ars_5 Ars_6 Ars_7
 1:    x   y1   z1 0.935 0.065 0.000 0.000     0     0     0     0
 2:    x   y2   z1 1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000     0     0     0     0
 3:    x   y1   z2 0.146 0.000 0.854 0.000     0     0     0     0
 4:    x   y2   z2 0.520 0.377 0.103 0.000     0     0     0     0
 5:    y   y1   z1 0.939 0.060 0.000 0.001     0     0     0     1
 6:    y   y2   z1 0.987 0.013 0.000 0.000     0     0     0     1
 7:    y   y1   z2 0.175 0.052 0.773 0.000     0     0     0     1
 8:    y   y2   z2 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000     0     0     0     1
 9:    z   y1   z1 0.948 0.052 0.000 0.000     0     0     0     1
10:    z   y2   z1 0.981 0.019 0.000 0.000     0     0     0     1
11:    z   y1   z2 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000     1     1     1     1
12:    z   y2   z2 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I am able to solve it partially but having two columns of Ars_7                             xds <- bind_rows(x1, x2 %>% select(var1, var2, var3) %>% unique() %>% 
                   anti_join(x1) %>% inner_join(x2))
xds <- bind_cols(xds, x2[!(names(x2) %in% names(x1))])

Comment: I find `dplyr` confusing personally, but if that works for you, great! I am writing a `data.table` solution since I find more legible for code purposes.